# How to handle form submission using Kotlin and Spring Boot

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-mvc

I am trying to use the Spring framework to make a simple form in Kotlin but when I click on submit, it only displays Result in h1 tags and nothing else

Here is my code:

```
@Controller
class HtmlController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    fun home(model: Model): String {
        model["title"] = "Homepage"
        model["greeting"] =  Greeting()
        return "home"
    }

    @PostMapping("/")
    fun greetingSubmit(@ModelAttribute greeting: Greeting?, model: Model): String? {
        model["title"] = "greeting"
        if (greeting != null) {
            model["greeting"] = greeting
        }
        return "result"
    }

}


// Greeting class
class Greeting {
    var id: Long = 0
    var content: String? = null
}
```

Here are my HTML templates:

```
<!-- result.mustache -->
{{> header}}

<h1>Result</h1>
<p th:text="'id: ' + ${greeting.id}" />
<p th:text="'content: ' + ${greeting.content}" />
<a href="/">Submit another message</a>

{{> footer}}
```

```
<!-- home.mustache -->
{{> header}}

<h1>Form</h1>
<form action="#" th:action="@{/greeting}" th:object="${greeting}" method="post">
    <p>Id: <input type="text" th:field="*{id}"/></p>
    <p>Message: <input type="text" th:field="*{content}"/></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"/> <input type="reset" value="Reset"/></p>
</form>

{{> footer}}
```

Comment: 1. `th:action="@{/greeting}"` is inconsitent with `@PostMapping("/")`!?

Comment: I tried that. Unfortunately, nothing changed.

Comment: 2. thymeleaf or mustache? (both are rather unconventional/very advanced)

Comment: I changed /greeting to / to match the post mapping in home.mustache. I am following this guide https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/ but it's in java and I want to learn how to do it in Kotlin. I am open to using other ways instead of thymeleaf.

Comment: the templates were taken from https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-kotlin/ for the header and footer. And when I hit the breakpoint greeting instance was initialized to 0 for id and null for content but I still can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I, too, tried to convert the guide to kotlin ... with following result:

https://github.com/xerx593/handlingformsubmission-kotlin

Key points:

- Controller is syntactically wrong (`model["xyz"]`), we can use `model.addAtribute(...)` or `model.asMap()["xyz"] = ...`
- Get mapping should match the request (+"submit another message") url
- Post mapping should match the `th:action` url
- Consistence of view and file name (+location): e.g.`"home"` -> `src/main/resources/templates/home.html`
- ...

Comment: Thanks a lot. For those of you getting circular path error, don't forget to add the thymeleaf dependency to your build.gradle.kts or if you are using maven then add it to your pom.xml.

Comment: The error was actually in using the mustache templates, ie using the header and footer tags. You were right they are unconventional/advanced and ended up copying your html templates and now it works fine.